# Unexpected module loading using `urllib` in python 3.5.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

There appears to be some unexpected behavior when it comes to phantom module loading with `urllib` on certain systems. The behavior is as follows:

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Aug 18 2017, 17:48:00) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import urllib
>>> dir(urllib)
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']
>>> urllib.foo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'foo'
>>> dir(urllib)
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', 'error', 'parse', 'request', 'response']
```

The unexpected behavior is that the additional names are loaded after only trying to access a bad attribute and getting a `AttributeError`. On another system with the same python interpreter (Ubuntu 16.04 `apt python3`) this does not happen:

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
>>> import urllib
>>> dir(urllib)
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']
>>> urllib.foo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'foo'
>>> dir(urllib)
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']
```

We have tested on several OSes and interpreters and the only other one that exhibits the unexpected behavior is an Ubuntu 14.04 Python 3.4.0 obtained from `apt`. On this system, we also verified that it seems to occur when a completely unrelated exceptions is raised as well...

```
Python 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:05:18) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> raise Exception('uh oh')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
Exception: uh oh
>>> import urllib
>>> dir(urllib)
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', 'error', 'parse', 'request', 'response']
```

What's going on here?

Comment: It's probably a system-level exception handler that logs exceptions. The exception handler loads `urllib.*` modules.

Comment: What does `import sys; print(sys.excepthook)` produce? And `print(sys.excepthook is sys.__excepthook__)`?

Comment: System in question: `<function apport_excepthook at 0x7f65c6acf510>` and `False`. "Normal" system: `<built-in function excepthook>` and `True`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have [Apport](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Apport) installed, a software package used by Ubuntu to capture software crashes.

The package includes a Python package that installs a [`sys.excepthook` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook); this hook is called whenever an *unhandled* exception is raised in a Python program. The implementation for that hook indirectly loads `urllib.*` modules.

By triggering an exception in the interactive interpreter, you triggered the hook, causing the extra Python code to run which adds imports.

See the [`apport_python_hook.py` source code](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~apport-hackers/apport/trunk/view/head:/apport_python_hook.py); when the hook is called, various `apport` modules are loaded, including [`apport.report`](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~apport-hackers/apport/trunk/view/head:/apport/report.py) which imports `urllib` modules.

You can disable the hook by setting `enabled = 0` in `/etc/default/apport`.

In future, if you want to see imports take place, you can run Python with the [`-v` command-line switch](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#id4) or setting the [`PYTHONVERBOSE` environment variable](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONVERBOSE); that'd have told you that the `apport_python_hook` module was loaded when you opened Python, and that more modules were loaded when the exception was raised.